# Table must have clickable cells to display more options from XML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I need to have a clickable cell within a table, so it will show a description of a TV show. I have it feeding in the XML to make the table called 'tvGuide1' and a tooltip like function shows a brief description. The XML create the first row with the first 5 elements within XML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "MonWedSatXML.xml",
cache: false,
success: function(xml){
$(xml).find('#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9, #10, #11, #12, #13, #14, #15, #16').each(function(){
var Time = $(this).find('Time').text();

dcs1 = $(this).find('Desc1').text();
dcs2 = $(this).find('Desc2').text();
dcs3 = $(this).find('Desc3').text();
dcs4 = $(this).find('Desc4').text();
dcs5 = $(this).find('Desc5').text();

var Program1 = $(this).find('Title1').text();
var Program2 = $(this).find('Title2').text();
var Program3 = $(this).find('Title3').text();
var Program4 = $(this).find('Title4').text();
var Program5 = $(this).find('Title5').text();

$('<tr></tr>').html('<th>'+Time+"</th><td Title='"+dcs1+"' <div onClick='info()'>"+Program1+"</td><td Title='"+dcs2+"'<div onClick='info()'>"+Program2+"</td><td Title='"+dcs3+"'<div onClick='info()'>"+Program3+"</td><td Title='"+dcs4+"'<div onClick='info()'>"+Program4+"</td><td Title='"+dcs5+"'>"+Program5+'</td>').appendTo('#tvGuide1');

});
}
});
$( "#tvGuide1" ).on("click","td", function(e){
console.log('hello');
$("#myModal").modal("show");
});
});
</script>
```

XML EXAMPLE

```
<Programs>
     <TVShows id="1">
     <Time>08:00</Time>
    <Title1>Breakfast</Title1>
    <Desc1>The latest news, sport, business and weather from the team. Also in HD. [S] Including regional news at 25 and 55 minutes past each hour.</Desc1>
  <Title2>Fake Britain</Title2>
<Desc2>Matt Allwright investigates the activities of conmen, revealing the fake high-EndTimesome farmers' markets and looking at counterfeit bike parts.</Desc2>
  <Title3>Family Guy</Title3>
  <Desc3>Hilarious show about a modern family</Desc3>
  <Title4>ITV News</Title4>
 <Desc4>Your latest news, sport and weather</Desc4>
 <Title5>Homes Under the Hammer</Title5>
 <Desc5>People buy rubbish houses and give them a make over then sell them</Desc5>
</TVShows>

      '<table id="tvGuide1">
    <tr>
    <th>Time 24hr Clock</th>
    <th>BBC 1<img src="Channel1.png" style="width:150px;height:150px"></th>
    <th>BBC 2<img src="Channel2.png" style="width:150px;height:150px"></th>
    <th>Comedy Central<img src="ComedyCentral.png" style="width:150px;height:150px"></th>
    <th>ITV<img src="Channel3.jpeg" style="width:150px;height:150px"></th>
    <th>Channel 4<img src="Channel4.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px"></th>
    </tr>
    </table>'
```

The problem the XML will create the table and pull in the data but I have no idea how to implement the modal to display the description from the XML
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the information you want to display in the modal as data-attributes to each `<td>` - e.g. like this:

```
<td data-desc="Hilarious show about a modern family">Family Guy</td>
```

and either add a class to each clickable `<td>` or check on click if this data-attribute is set:

```
$("td").on("click", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if($(this).data("desc")){
    modal($(this).data("desc"));
  }
});
```

with either a self written modal function or an existing solution. As example I've just created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37na9jg7/) with a simple modal function and set the data for the first three entries. In case you have more information that you want to display in the modal, this can be added as another data-attribute. This is only an example, as you already have set the short description as `title`-tag I suppose there's an additional longer description in the XML that you would like to only display in a modal.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/data/

**Update:** For the mentioned requirement to get the description for the modal from the XML on click on `td` - following approach:

```
function loadXml(item) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'programs.xml',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        parseXml(xml, item);
    }
  });
}

function parseXml(xml, item) {
  var $xml = $(xml),
      desc = $xml.find(item).text();
  modal(desc);
}

function modal(desc) {
  $("body").addClass("inactive");
  $("#modal").text(desc).show();
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".programm td").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    if (col > 0) {
        loadXml("Desc" + col);
    }

  });
  $("body").on("click", function (e) {
    if (!$("#modal").is(e.target)) {
        $("#modal").hide();
        $("body").removeClass("inactive");
    }
  });
});
```

Adjusted but not working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zqsej4q/) - not working because the XML (even if referenced as absolute URL) wouldn't be readable from there because of CORS. The XML has to be on the same domain as the page that's reading the XML, so for testing purposes I've just uploaded it on a testserver and it's working, using an absolute URL to the XML as well as using the relative URL when the XML is next to the HTML.
As explanation - each `tr` has the class `programm`, on click of an `td` with an index > 0 (as the first `td` with index 0 is the time) calls the function `loadXml()` with desc + index of the clicked `td` as parameter. On success, `parseXml()` is called, retrieves the text of the description (e.g. Desc2) and calls the `modal()` function with the retrieved text.
I've only written this as an example for the XML you provided, as you will have more entries, e.g. for the next time slot under  `<TVShows id="2">`, you can adjust this to take the number/index of the clicked `tr` with class `programm` into account.

Comment: Hard coding all of them would be too time consuming as it is a TVGuide, so I would like to be able to click on the title of the show and it pull the data from the XML (description). Its an idea I have thought off but I dont know how to write the code to pull the data from the XML :-/

Comment: @Relentless Understandable, so I've just updated my answer for this.